# Spinning wheel on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a spinning wheel on React with 20 elements coming from a json. They have a name and an odds attribute. There is a spin button that when you press it the wheel spins for two laps and then it stops at the winning element, which is calculated each time during the spin and it's based on their odds. Everything works fine on the first spin, but when i try to spin again (the idea is that it behaves the same way than in the beginning, but starting from the last winning item instead) the spin becomes much slower and it sometimes spins backwards. How can i keep track of the previous position and make it always spin for at least two laps no matter what?

This is what i have so far:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { Items } from './mocks/items.json'
import './App.css'

// Calculate the total odds
const totalOdds = Items.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.odds, 0);

function App() {
  const [spinning, setSpinning] = useState(false);
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null);
  const wheelRef = useRef();

  const spin = () => {
    setSpinning(true);

    // Calculate the winning element
    let random = Math.random() * totalOdds;
    let currentOdds = 0;
    let currentSpinCount = 0;
    let currentWinner = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
      currentOdds += Items[i].odds;
      if (random <= currentOdds) {
        currentWinner = Items[i];
        currentSpinCount = 2 * Items.length + i;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Spin the wheel
    wheelRef.current.style.transitionDuration = `${currentSpinCount * 200}ms`;
    wheelRef.current.style.transform = `rotate(-${(360 / Items.length) *
      currentSpinCount}deg)`;

    // Set the winner after the wheel stops spinning
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSpinning(false);
      setWinner(currentWinner);
    }, currentSpinCount * 200);
  };

  return (
    <div className="wheel-container">
      <div
        className={`wheel ${spinning ? "spinning" : ""}`}
        ref={wheelRef}
      >
        {Items.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`${
              winner && winner.name === item.name ? "winner" : ""
            }`}
            style={{
              transform: `rotate(${(360 / Items.length) * index}deg)`,
            }}
          >
            {item.name}
            <div className="odds">{(item.odds * 100).toFixed(2)}%</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button
        className="spin-button"
        onClick={spin}
        disabled={spinning}
      >
        {spinning ? "Spinning..." : "Spin"}
      </button>
      {winner && (
        <div className="winner">
          The winner is <span>{winner.name}</span>!
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```